# Is it required to set a period after the paragraph title?

Tags: punctuation

My question is whether this

> **Konvertierung in JavaScript-Objekte.**  Als erster Schritt wird in der Applika-
>   tion die CSV-Datei in *JavaScript-Objekte* umgewandelt. Das Laden und *Parsing* der
>   Datei von CSV zu Objekten ist von D3 implementiert.

or this

> **Konvertierung in JavaScript-Objekte**  Als erster Schritt wird in der Applika-
>   tion die CSV-Datei in *JavaScript-Objekte* umgewandelt. Das Laden und *Parsing* der
>   Datei von CSV zu Objekten ist von D3 implementiert.

is correct, i.e. whether a title that is integrated into a paragraph should be followed by a period or not.

Comment: Hi and welcome to German Language Stack Exchange. Feel free to take a [tour] of the site and visit the [help] to learn more about it. We would prefer for you to include the Text as *text* rather than an image, because images are not searchable.

Comment: You would usually wrap the text into the next line. Then it looks much more like a title or header.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not as clear as it looks. We have two possible interpretations.

1. **We are dealing with a classical heading that is small enough and semi-integrated into the text.** In this case, the § 68 of the official German orthographic rules is relevant:

   > § 68: Nach freistehenden Zeilen setzt man keinen Punkt.

   Considering it a classical title and removed from the surrounding text, no full stop is allowed. This interpretation is the one T Sieksmeier follows in her answer and the one Em1 follows in a comment to your question.
2. **We are dealing with a boldfaced sentence introducing the following.** In your case, this interpretation is slightly streched because there is no verb in your preceding sentence. However there could be one. In this case, the only real rule kicking in is § 67:

   > § 67: Mit dem Punkt kennzeichnet man den Schluss eines Ganzsatzes.

   It might seem weird because the ‘sentence’ we are talking about does not contain a verb. However:

   > Ganzsätze im Sinne dieser orthografischen Regelung zeigen Beispiele wie:
   >   *[…] Warum nicht? Gute Reise! Hilfe!*

   Thus it seems allowed to consider this type a sentence, too.

Whether you prefer interpretation 1 or interpretation 2 is really up to the bit in question and (most importantly!) its surroundings. If the title is really only relevant for the following information and is further separated by spacing as it seems to be the case in your example, I would prefer interpretation 1. However, I can think of instances where interpretation 2 would be at least equally valid.

Comment: Nicht nur steht die Zeile nicht frei, sie ist nicht einmal eine. Der Punkt wird daher benötigt.

Answer (score 2):

Your second example *Konvertierung in JavaScript-Objekte* without the period is the right one.

As it is written in the *Duden* headings (headings of paragraphs, too) require no period. Headings aren't full sentences (in your example the verb is missing), that's why we don't need to put a period at the end of them.

Here's the link to a german version of the *Duden*: http://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/rechtschreibregeln/punkt where your question is well explained.

Comment: "Headings aren't full sentences" -> What happens **if** the title is a full sentence? ;)